# Select to wide reshape of table with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, pivot

I have this table scheme:

```
 pcode   city    
 1       MAD     
 3       MAD     
 3       LON     
 1       MAD     
 2       LON     
 3       MAD     
 1       LON     
 2       LON
```

and I want this result:

```
 pcode    cityMAD    cityLON
 1        2          1
 2        0          2
 3        2          1
```

I mean, I need a `SELECT` to 'reshape' the table, counting the number of observations for every pcode and city.

The table is quite big (>100,000 obs). The number of different pcode's is unknown, but the number of different cities is small, so I can include the names of the cities in the `SELECT`.

Comment: I think this is actually bad design. I think a better table should be one with `(pcode,city,count)`...

Comment: Of course it would be, but the actual table is much more complex than this one, and this is what I have to deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the following query:

```
SELECT pcode,
       SUM(city='MAD') as cityMAD,
       SUM(city='LON') as cityLON
FROM table
GROUP BY pcode
```

but then you'll need to create all desired columns manually.

Maybe you should `group by` both `pcode` and `city`, and use pivot table.

note that `SUM` receives 1 when True and 0 when False automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You can build query like below:

```
select pcode,
sum(case when city = 'MAD' then 1 ELSE 0 END) as cityMAD,
sum(case when city = 'LON' then 1 ELSE 0 END) as cityLON
from table_name
group by pcode;
```

You need to add `sum` for each city like I have adde for cityMAD and cityLON.

Comment: Thank you. Perfect answer. I accept the one by Dimgold due to he/she uses less code.